# vagrant & chef-solo don't work with mysql and apache2

Tags: mysql, ruby, apache, vagrant, chef-solo

i try to setup a new vagrant project. But i can't start the vagrant vm.

My Vagrantfile looks like this:

```
    config.vm.box = "precise64"
    config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box"

    config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
          chef.cookbooks_path = "~/chef-repo/cookbooks"
          chef.roles_path = "~/chef-repo/roles"`enter code here`
          chef.data_bags_path = "~/chef-repo/data_bags"
          chef.add_recipe "apache2"
          chef.add_recipe "mysql::server"

    end
```

When i run 'vagrant up'. i get this.

```
    ==> default: Relevant File Content:
    ==> default: ----------------------
    ==> default: /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/provider_mysql_service_rhel.rb:
    ==> default: 
    ==> default:   1:  require 'chef/provider/lwrp_base'
    ==> default:   2:  require 'shellwords'
    ==> default:   3:  require_relative 'helpers'
    ==> default:   4:  
    ==> default:   5:  extend Opscode::Mysql::Helpers
    ==> default:   6:  
    ==> default:   7:  class Chef
    ==> default:   8:    class Provider
    ==> default:   9:      class MysqlService
    ==> default: [2014-07-31T11:57:50+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
    ==> default: [2014-07-31T11:57:50+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
    ==> default: [2014-07-31T11:57:50+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
    ==> default: [2014-07-31T11:57:50+00:00] FATAL: LoadError: no such file to load -- chef/provider/lwrp_base
```

Vagrant 1.6.3
Chef: 11.12.8
ruby: ruby 2.0.0p451

any body an idea how can i solve this.

Comment: What is your chef version on the VM? Try this: https://github.com/schisamo/vagrant-omnibus

Comment: The Version is 11.14.2 as well. I Tried this with omnibus - same result.